# Le "braccia delle palme" sono le loro foglie?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Sostiene Pereira*, di Antonio Tabucchi, ho letto:

> Si misse a fissare le **braccia delle palme** che si agitavano al vento e pensò alla sua infanzia.

La mia domanda è: le "braccia delle palme" sono le foglie delle palme? Ho cercato alla voce "braccio" in alcuni dizionari, ma non ho saputo trovare niente che faccia riferimento agli alberi o alle palme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solitamente ci si riferisce ai rami come le "braccia di un albero". Nel caso della palma distinguere tra ramo e foglia diventa un po più complicato.

Comunque, non essendo un esperto, direi che i rami della palma sono quelli che dipartono dal fusto e sostengono le foglie più piccole.

Nel contesto da te citato l'autore si riferisce appunto a questi rami che oscillavano a causa del vento e lo facevano tornare indietro con la mente alla sua infanzia.

[image: Rami di palma]