# Che cosa significa "sbracciarsi" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Il barone rampante*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto:

> Cosimo era sull'elce. I rami **si sbracciavano**, alti ponti sopra la terra. Tirava un lieve vento; c'era sole.

Potreste spiegarmi il senso di "sbracciarsi" in questo brano? Ho cercato il verbo "sbracciare" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato nessuna accezione che abbia a che vedere con gli alberi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nel contesto da te citato sbracciare significa diramarsi dal fusto dell'albero e protendersi verso l'alto, come se i rami fossero braccia.

Già in un'altra domanda "[Le braccia delle palme sono le foglie](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9231/le-braccia-delle-palme-sono-le-loro-foglie/9232#9232)" si faceva riferimento ai rami come braccia dell'albero.

Inoltre i rami mossi dal vento, paragonati a braccia, ricordano lo sbracciarsi di una persona per attirare l'attenzione.